# push value in map of arrays at a specific postition

Tags: javascript

I am creating a map of array using this:

```
var m = new Map(Array(40).fill(new Array()).entries());
```

Now, I want to push values in those array. But when I do this:

```
m.get(1).push(10)
```

The value 10 gets pushed into all the arrays instead of the one at 1st position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take another pattern to build independent arrays.

```js
var m = new Map(Array.from({ length: 40 }, _=> []).entries());
m.get(1).push(10);

console.log([...m]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fill` gets `single array` an uses it to fill all rows of the given array, it doesn't create a new array for each row. This means that your **single array reference** is shared between all rows. Because `array` is a reference type, you use the single reference to manipulate it, so the actual object is changed. You can check this by comparing the references of each row.

```js
const arr = new Array(2).fill(new Array());

console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]);
```

For creating separate arrays, you can see **@Nina's answer** above

Comment: You're only confirming what the OP figured out...

Comment: Need each answer to have full answer to the question, every aspect???

Comment: Can't it refer some part to another one?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You're not explaining how to properly set a value in only one position of the "map".

Comment: See also the above comment

Comment: _"Look at this other answer"_ ___Isn't an answer___. If I realize changing my car's wheels in a swamp isn't working, and want to know how to change a wheel, _"Yea, cars tend to sink in swamps"_ doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Can't be it be like to a `link to another source`. What if the source is another answer?

Comment: A answer can't be a _"link to another source"_. If that other source changes or is removed, the answer loses all value. Come on, with 20k, you should know this by now.